# Python SimpleHTTPRequestHandler to play sound async

Tags: python, winsound, simplehttprequesthandler

I can't figure out how to make this small http server reply the get request and play a sound in parallel.

Current code, does not close the get request until the sound "winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)" end playing.

What i need is for the sound to be async to the request so that the get request ends asap and the sound keeps playing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, test
import socketserver
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
import sys
import winsound



class MyHttpRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    try:

        def do_GET(self):
            # Sending an '200 OK' response
            self.send_response(200)

            # Setting the header
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")

            # Whenever using 'send_header', you also have to call 'end_headers'
            self.end_headers()


            html = "ok"
            # Writing the HTML contents with UTF-8
            self.wfile.write(bytes(html, "utf8"))            
            winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)

            return

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))



# Create an object of the above class
handler_object = MyHttpRequestHandler

PORT = 8000
my_server = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), handler_object)

# Star the server
my_server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

**BACKGROUND**

*So basically, it's question about execution scope in Python. Back to your code above, in order for request to finish it has to be execute all task.*

- send response (this one doesn't make effect, because you have to return result from the method get)
- setting headers
- playing music

*Obviously, you return at the end of the request execution and your thread monitor just one. So request will finish after finishing all the tasks.*

**SOLUTION**

So as you mentioned in the question, you are right. To play music on your Server on the request, you have to run async task and **let you request return result from get request**. For ex. by using `asyncio` (it's very handy lib, so check it out)

```
import asyncio
import socketserver
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import winsound


class MyHttpRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    try:

        def do_GET(self):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.wfile.write(bytes("Ok", "utf8"))

            # Shared Queue of Background Tasks
            asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
                MyHttpRequestHandler.play_music()
            )

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

    @staticmethod
    async def play_music():
        try:
            print('Playing sound!')
            winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)

        # Maybe you want to add Error handling
        finally:
            pass


# Create an object of the above class
handler = MyHttpRequestHandler


server = socketserver.TCPServer(
    ("", 8000), handler)


# Star the server
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: It does not work for me, tested your code pasting it directly and does not work

Comment: @user8459020 Any failures or exceptions? Or sound just doesn't work.

Comment: @user8459020 updated code above, just a minor typo

Answer (score 1):

Use a [flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_ASYNC) to run it async:

```
winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS|winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

If you wish to have tighter control, use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()` to run it in a different thread:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import winsound

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()

class MyHttpRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    try:

        def do_GET(self):
            # Sending an '200 OK' response
            self.send_response(200)

            # Setting the header
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")

            # Whenever using 'send_header', you also have to call 'end_headers'
            self.end_headers()


            html = "ok"
            # Writing the HTML contents with UTF-8
            self.wfile.write(bytes(html, "utf8"))

            pool.submit(winsound.PlaySound, "SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)

            return

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```